# Set ACL of s3 Bucket item in dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-s3

I'm using dotnet 6 with AWS Sdk for dotnet.
I want to change the ACL of a specific file through C# code. I found the method of getting a pre-signed url, but it's not really what I'm looking for.. I'll explain better:

I need my file set publicRead as ACL so that people can access to that with url similar to that:
https://mys3bucket.com/mypicture.jpg
That is mandatory, it sounds strange but I need it work only in that way, I need the name of the file at the end of the URL, and presigned url won't work because they add all they need to work inside the URL.
Not going into further details but basically I'm using a certain library on FrontEnd which will call files from BE with URL + nameOfTheFile, and all I can personalize is the URL before, can't do any other edits.
From s3 site UI, if I select the file, I do 'Operations' and then 'Make public using ACL', the file is accessible from the basic URL (the one I need). That's what I need to do, but from C# code. I want to be able to set a certain file (or folder would be better, but I can workaround that easily with a for loop) as public and, when needed, set this file back as private.

How can I do that? I found similar but not what I'm looking for, as I said the presigned, and when uploading a file, uploading it already as public, but still would not work because I want to be able to set it back to private when needed.